# Neater Folder Sharing with gData Python API

Tags: python, google-drive-api, gdata

I am currently working on a project that automatically shares Google Drive folders
with students and teachers based on our enrollment database.

This system will be used as an easy way for students and teachers to share files.

A big part of this project is keeping everything strucured so it is easy for everybody to use.

I currently have code that creates the structure in a specific google drive account, then shares it with the appropriate students and teacher:

```
-- Class Folders (Stores all the assignment and class folders)
-- Student (Stores all the shared Root student folders)
---- Student (id #) (Root student folder to be shared with student)
------ Courses (Holds all classes student is enrolled in)
-------- Algebra 1 (Example Class Folder)
---------- Class Files (Copy of Class Files the teacher shares with all students in class)
---------- Student Name - Assignments (Shared with teacher and student)
-- Teacher (Stores all the shared Root teacher folders)
---- Teacher (id #) (Root teacher folder to be shared with teacher)
------ Courses (Holds all the courses teacher is teaching)
-------- Algebra 1 (Example Class Folder)
---------- Class Files (Shared with students in class)
---------- Student 1 - Assignments
---------- Student 2 - Assignments
```

Above is the current folder structure.

When sharing the folders with everybody some of the permissions need to be modified, once you modify the permissions of a folder or add a user it shows up in the root of their "Shared with me" on Google Drive.

So after looping through the structure and everything is shared, the student and teacher "Shared with me" area looks like a mess. Instead of just seeing the root "Teacher" or "Student" folder, they see that and all the other folders that have been share with them.

I'd like to find a way to contain all the shared folders in the root "Teacher" and "Student" folders so it is easier for them to find that folder and move it to their Drive.

Here are some images for a clearer example of what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image: This is currently what is happening]

As you can see above the students assignment folder is outside of the "Teacher" folder,
Once the full batch runs this will get messy because the teacher will see all of their students outside of their root folder.

[image: This is what I'm looking for]

This picture shows what I'm looking for, one root folder visible for the teacher to move to "My Drive"

Currently the project is written in Python using the gData Python API,
Here is the code that I wrote to share folders.

```
def share(client, folder_id, share_with, role):
    update_acl = False
    updated = False
    folder = client.GetResourceById(folder_id)
    acl_feed = client.GetResourceAcl(folder)
    try:
        for acl in acl_feed.entry:
            if acl.scope.value == share_with:
                print "DEBUG: ACL for %s exists, verifying role." % share_with
                update_acl = acl
        if update_acl:
            if update_acl.role.value == role:
                print "DEBUG: Current ACL entry Okay. %s = %s" % (update_acl.role.value, role)
            else:
                print "DEBUG: ACL Scope: %s ACL Role: %s" % (update_acl.scope.value, update_acl.role.value)
                update_acl.role.value = role
                update_acl.etag = None
                print "DEBUG: ACL Scope: %s ACL Role: %s" % (update_acl.scope.value, update_acl.role.value)
                client.UpdateAclEntry(update_acl, send_notification=False)
            updated = True
        #add new ACL entry with proper role for share_with
        elif not updated:
            print "DEBUG: Sharing with %s" % share_with
            acl_entry = gdata.docs.data.AclEntry(
                scope=gdata.acl.data.AclScope(value=share_with, type='user'),
                role=gdata.acl.data.AclRole(value=role))
            client.AddAclEntry(folder, acl_entry, send_notification=False)
    except (gdata.client.RequestError):
        pass
```

Comment: Not an answer to the question, but given what you're trying to achieve, you should check out http://gcdc2013-student-drive.appspot.com/

Comment: Looks like an interesting project, not quite what I'm looking for. But thanks for the suggestion!